# Are locations random?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

With 'Pavle, Bruno, Marko' story, my playthrough got messed up because Garage never showed up. Are locations completely random and if so, would Garage show up eventually?

Comment: From my experiences with the editor, it is possible to select which locations are included in the setting. I would assume that garage will never show up in this particular scenario.

Comment: @antipattern  Is editor like a mod or is it part of the vanilla game? I haven't seen this option in any of the menu options. Thanks

Comment: It's in the vanilla game. Not sure how it is called, but it will be installed with the game normally. I think it is called scenario editor or similar. As far as i can remember, it is a different application (not _inside_ the game), but can be found in the base game folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I experienced, if your safehouse contains a tree-house in the backyard, then garage will not show up in that story playthrough. I still need to verify this with more playthrough. If someone can positively verify, please edit the answer.